# Is there a way to jump back and forth from python and JS?

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome-extension, youtube-api

I'm trying to create a chrome extension which are made in JS, however I built the main part of the code in python because it is the language I know, and I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is even possible in JS. Is there a way to take in a variable I get from JS, use it to run a python function, and then continue with the JS code?

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab){ 
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
var tabId = tab.id;
tabUrl = tab.url;
id = tabUrl.split("=")[1];
//call python func here
});
  var newURL = "frame.html";
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL});

});
```

```py
from youtube_transcript_api import YouTubeTranscriptApi
import webbrowser

def func(id):
    html_file = open('frame.html','w')
    list = YouTubeTranscriptApi.get_transcript(id)
    webbrowser.get('C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s')

    data = '<html>\n<head>\n<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">\n</head>\n<body>\n<p>\n' 
    for i in list:
        data += i.get('text') + ' '

    data += '</p>\n</body>\n</html>'
    html_file.write(data)
    html_file.close()

#func(id from java)
```

Comment: Maybe `Brython` is your best choice..

Comment: This approach won't work, probably, because modifying a file inside the extension directory will disable it because Chrome verifies checksums of all files. Judging by the code it's a rather basic task for JS: query the API and modify DOM.